# How do I get only unique results from two dissimilar arrays?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

This might seem like a duplicate question, but I can't find any information on this. I want to show the results from a remotely acquired json array excluding certain results by comparing them to a local table. I have a gallery model with:

```
t.integer :smugmug_id
t.string :smugmug_key
t.integer :category_id
t.string :category_name
t.string :description
t.integer :highlight_id
t.string :highlight_key
t.string :highlight_type
t.string :keywords
t.string :nicename
t.integer :subcategory_id
t.string :subcategory_name
t.string :title
t.string :url
```

The data for this model gets populated by a rake task that connects to the smugmug api (json) and stores the data locally. I'm trying to create a view that shows all the smugmug galleries that are not stored locally.

Here's what I've tried so far, but it's not excluding the locally stored galleries like I thought it would.

```
def self.not_stored
  smugmug_list = Smug::Client.new.albums(heavy = true)
  gallery_list = Gallery.select(:smugmug_id)
  smugmug_list.each do |smugmug|
    smugmug unless gallery_list.include? smugmug.id
  end
end
```

Hopefully this makes sense. I'm getting a json array of galleries, and I want to display that array excluding results where the album id matches the smugmug_id of any of my locally stored records.

Quick edit: I'm using an adaptation of [this gem](https://github.com/bensie/smirk) to connect to the smugmug api.

Comment: how about `desired_ids = smugmug_list.map{|s|s.id}-gallery_list`?  This should work if gallery_list is an array of integer ids.

Comment: Can you provide some information on the expected size of the json array you're getting from smugmug, and the size (=number of records) in your local table?

Comment: @Elad: the size is not relevant here; `Array#-` is `O(n)`.

Comment: @marc-andre-lafortune size matters exactly because it's O(n) - that's the meaning of the little n in there...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the [difference operator](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000273).

General Example:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :001 > [3,2,1] - [2,1]
 => [3]
```

So you would have:

```
smugmug_list.collect{|e| e.id} - gallery_list
```

[Enumerable#collect](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001490) will turn the smugmug_list into a list of id's. From there, you can do the difference operator, which will return all the id's of all the smugmug galleries that are not stored locally.

Another option to maintain the list of galleries:

```
smugmug_list.select{|e|!gallery_list.include?(e.id)}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to convert that list of ids back into a list of galleries from smugmug, which is the reason I was trying the 'unless' clause.

Comment: Fantastic, Thanks. I didn't realize I could run select on the json array.

Comment: for some reason this code isn't working today. I'm baffled as to why it worked yesterday, but now it's not restricting the smugmug_list results. I've typed and retyped it all day, and can't figure out what changed.